# Jtoken cast to int error

Tags: c#, json.net

```
{"Score":"1851","HistoryScore":"3149","TotalScore":"3149","TotalTopic":"289"}
```

image have an above json

```
int i = (int)x["Score"]
```

this is ok  and  i = 1851;

if has a Extension method as next

```
public static T As<T>(this object @this)
{
    return (T) @this;
}
x["Score"].as<int>();`
// this will get error why? System.InvalidCastException
```

Comment: There is already [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The library implements explicit casting operators; which allows you to cast a `JToken` to `int` without receiving an error.

Your extension, however, is first casting the `JToken` to an `object`, and *then* casting to `int`. Since there's no explicit conversion from `object` to `int`, you're getting an exception.

Why not define the extension as follows:

```
public static T As<T>(this JToken @this)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(@this, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Thank you  why not directly ` return (T)@this;` are there any difference

Comment: @Isl Yes, you'll get a compiler error; since it's unable to infer that any `JToken` will be safely castable to `T`.

Comment: You can as well change that to `this object @this`, since it's not specific to `JToken`s